# how to make component not re-render when next page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i'm doing asynchronous processing while waiting for `created` to finish then start running `mouted` , everything is fine, but something is causing my component to re-render, looks like this: [video](https://tikho900-gmail.tinytake.com/df/13e1429/thumbnail?type=attachments&version_no=0&file_version_no=0&thumbnail_size=preview)

 how do i handle the above problem
here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-panel">
      <dashboard-content @click.native="toggleSidebar" />
    </div>
    <Sidebar :sidebar-data="dataSidebar"/>
  </div>
</template>  

data() {
    return {
      dataSidebar: [],
      role: adminRole.OWNER,
      isPending: null, // Save promise handler
    };
  },
  created() {
    if (!(STORE_ADMIN_AUTH_KEY in this.$store._modules.root._children)) {
      this.$store.registerModule(STORE_ADMIN_AUTH_KEY, store);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem(ADMIN_AUTH_TOKEN_KEY)) {
      const res = this.$store.dispatch(STORE_ADMIN_AUTH_KEY + "/getInfo");
      this.isPending = new Promise((solver, reject) => {
        res.then((data) => {
          localStorage.setItem("AUTH",JSON.stringify(data.role ? data.role : adminRole.OWNER));
          solver();
        });
      });
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.isPending;
    this.getSitebarItems();
  },
  methods: {
    getSitebarItems() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("AUTH")) {
        this.role = localStorage.getItem("AUTH");
      }
      if (this.role == adminRole.OWNER) {
        this.dataSidebar = sidebarItems;
        return;
      }

      sidebarItems.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.onlyOwner == 0) {
          this.dataSidebar.push(element);
        }
      });
    },
  },
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe `await this.isPending;` could be moved to `created()`

Comment: @Jonathan how can i fix that

Comment: see my answer as a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try creating a copy of the items to prevent triggering reactivity.

```
getSitebarItems() {
    let data = sidebarItems.slice();
    if (this.role == adminRole.OWNER) {
      this.dataSidebar = data;
      return;
    }

    data = data.filter((element) => {
        return element.onlyOwner == 0;
    });
    this.dataSidebar = data;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work